# trying to add custom widget to spacemacs spaceline

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm struggling to find the best practice for adding in a new widget in spaceline within spacemacs.
The best I have so far is to redfine the battery segment:

```
(spaceline-define-segment battery
   (shell-command-to-string "echo 'hello'"))
```

but this then slows down spacemacs considerably so it seems like there must be a refresh parameter somewhere? There doesn't appear to be an `async-shell-command-to-string` function either.

Total emacs newbie here, as you can tell.

Comment: What do you intend by "widget" here? A widget in Emacs is a particular thing, used mainly in `*Customize*` buffers. But it doesn't seem like that's what you mean here.

Comment: @Drew apols for late reply, i just mean a custom element in the spaceline